# windows 7 on Acer Aspire

Tags: windows-7, acer-aspire

I have a notebook Acer Aspire 5940G, I had windows home prem. it was working great and I had full performance but now I have windows 7 ultimate edition. but it is not working as the other one. some functions stoped working, I have all drivers installed and I am not sure what is missing, even some functions from taskbar stoped working.

for example: when I pressed the button for bluetooth to start it showed me a notification that it was starting.. now it doesnt. should I install home edition of windows 7 again or anything else is missing to the notebook?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's hard to tell what could be wrong. You should try to include more details if possible. What "bluetooth notification" did you see, and what taskbar functions are missing? Did you have custom software before? Perhaps there was some bloatware that you used that you're missing now.

Comment: a notification like a pop up. you know you press the bluetooth button in the taskbar and then in the monitor it pop ups a fast alert/notification that is telling you that the bluetooth is starting up. I also think that it had some costume software before but I am not sure!

Comment: If the bit-levels are the same between Windows editions (ie: 32-bit vs. 64-bit) then the same drivers should work (the same) for all editions of 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Windows 7 does not include any bluetooth software, so it sounds like you had some pre-installed software that was removed during your upgrade. I suggest you search around for the right bluetooth software and drivers for your machine, and any other programs for functionality that you are now missing.